# Is it possible to use JMF in Android?

Tags: android, jmf, rtp

The reason why I want to use JMF in Android is to send out RTP from Android.
Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: i think you dont need to use JMF in android. There is much better API available in android.

Comment: But there's no APIs about RTP. How to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [android.net.rtp](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/package-summary.html) package for RTP